# Iterating my function by $4$ using NestList -- Syntax Confusion

Tags: functions, syntax

I want to iterate my function $f(x) = 13xe^{-x}$ by $4$ multiple times. That is, $f, f^{4}, f^{8}, f^{12},\cdots$. Using `Nestlist[f,x,4]` I can get $f,f^{(2)}, f^{(3)},f^{(4)}$, but I only want the 4th iterations. I cannot find the correct way to do this in mathematica. Can anyone please show me the correct syntax for this?

Comment: `g[x_] = Nest[f, x, 4]; NestList[g, x, 2]` is one possibility. Another is `NestList[f, x, 16][[1 ;; ;; 4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Nest` and `Map`.

```
Nest[f, x, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 12, 4]
```

Hope this helps.